# Finding the mode of each column in a two-dimensional array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Not a question, just putting this out there if someone would need it. (caused me a lot of headache)

The script below can take a 2d array of any number number of 2nd-layer arrays as 'myArray' and create a single array of the most frequent element (regardless of type) in each column of the original 2d array.

```js
myArray = myArray[0]
  .map((_, col) => myArray.map((row) => row[col]))
  .map((array) =>
    array.reduce(
      (a, b, i, arr) =>
        arr.filter((v) => v === a).length >= arr.filter((v) => v === b).length
          ? a
          : b,
      null
    )
  );
```

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but your question should still read like a question, and your answer should also read like an answer (with details on how the code works and what it is doing)

Comment: It wasn't a question that needs answering (by me or anyone else), just something that I could find no answer for, and decided to leave this here for posterity @NickParsons

Comment: Yes, but your question should still be formed in a way that follows the q & a format of Stack Overflow. Your question should be something along the lines of "I have this array of numbers <show array>, and I am wanting to find the mode of each column. I am wanting to achieve the following <result>." (and potentially add links to similar questions that might be related that didn't answer this question) that at leasts shows future readers what you're trying to achieve and do. Your explanation of the code that you have in your question should be in the body of your answer.

Comment: See updated answer..@NickParsons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it does:
The code below will take any two-dimensional array “myArray” and return a one-dimensional array with the mode of each column of the original 2-d array.

How it works:
The input (2-d array) is transposed and the resulting array is searched for the most common element in each row. It is then reduced to then flattened (reduced) and re-transposed to a 1d array containing the most common elements of each column of the original array.

```js
myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7],
  [1, 3, 3, 6, 7],
  [1, 5, 3, 4, 7],
  [1, 6, 3, 4, 7],
  [1, 7, 3, 8, 5],
];

myArray = myArray[0]
  .map((_, col) => myArray.map((row) => row[col]))
  .map((array) =>
    array.reduce(
      (a, b, i, arr) =>
      arr.filter((v) => v === a).length >= arr.filter((v) => v === b).length ?
      a :
      b,
      null
    )
  );

console.log(myArray);
```